# Ruby on Rails redirect how to pass params in routes file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-status-code-301, rails-routing

We recently changed the product name on our website from 'bracelets' to 'wristbands' and need to keep the old routes around for SEO purposes.

Essentially, these routes

www.hostname.com/products/bracelets/series-1/
www.hostname.com/products/bracelets/series-1/small-purple

should route to

www.hostname.com/products/wristbands/series-1/
www.hostname.com/products/wristbands/series-1/small-purple

I am reading the tutorial here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection and looks like i'll be using the block syntax, but am still not sure how to do the route properly. I'm looking to learn more about the routes file as well, so any information would be great. Thanks in advance

```
match "/bracelets/:name" => redirect {|params| "/wristbands/#{params[:name]}" }
```

EDIT:

OK i've been playing with it for a bit, and here is how it is working with what I have tried

```
match "/products/bracelets/:name/:name2" => redirect {|params| "/products/wristbands/#{params[:name].pluralize}/#{params[:name2].pluralize}" }
```

Input URL: 
*localhost:3000/products/bracelets/series-1/small-purple*

Output URL: *localhost:3000/products/wristbands*
Error Message: Invalid Product: series-1
(So the match worked, but the redirect didn't)

If I change the match to inspect params like this:

```
match "/products/balance-bracelets/:name/:name2" => redirect {|params| "/products/wristbands/#{params.inspect}" }
```

I get the following:

```
 /products/wristbands/{:name=>"series-1", :name2=>"small-purple"}
```

So it appears it isn't recognizing the second slash '/' or something. Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you explain how it is working right now with what you've tried ?

Comment: I added some details thanks, any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm was at the same situation and that works for me:

```
match "/products/bracelets/:name/:name2" => redirect {|params, request| "/products/wristbands/#{params[:name].pluralize}/#{params[:name2].pluralize}" }
```

I've passed two agruments into the block.

Comment: Looks like we came up with roughly the same solution, however in my case I didn't need to pass request in (wasn't using it) and removing .pluralize on both name and name2 worked for me.

Comment: is this secure? i'm going to double check some references to figure out if passing values like this isn't vulnerable to SQL injections... but does anybody here have a reference keyword handy that i can look up to double check?

Comment: I don't think that related. All that it does is redirecting from one URL to another. All the security issues, such as SQL injections, should be addressed separately.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in Rails 5.

```
match '/products/bracelets/:name/:name2', to: "/products/wristbands/%{name}/%{name2}"
```