# How to pass new params to a redirect in routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes, parameters

There are several questions, which explain how to pass request parameters to a redirect ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943169/rails-routes-how-to-pass-all-request-params-in-a-redirect) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906097/ruby-on-rails-redirect-how-to-pass-params-in-routes-file)). However, I don't see from their answers how to insert new parameters that weren's in the request already.

I want to do something like:

```
get '/models', to: redirect('/models?foo=bar&baz=qux')
```

When I do this, I get:

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/models
Completed 302 Found in 2704ms (ActiveRecord: 140.6ms)


Started GET "/models" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-18 16:51:31 +0200


Started GET "/models?foo=bar&baz=qux" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-18 16:51:31 +0200


Started GET "/models?foo=bar&baz=qux" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-18 16:51:31 +0200


Started GET "/models?foo=bar&baz=qux" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-18 16:51:31 +0200


Started GET "/models?foo=bar&baz=qux" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-18 16:51:31 +0200
```

and eventually `This page has a redirect loop`.

Probably I shouldn't do this in the routes.rb, but assign default values of the index action in the controller, but the thing is I want my page to have `?foo=bar&baz=qux` appended to the URL. How can I do this?

Comment: Why would you want this?  Can't you just specify in your controller that if those params aren't there do whatever?

Comment: The thing is I am highlighting certain tabs in the navigation based on the location of the page, using `current_page?` method. The highlighting depends on query parameters/instance variables. Basically all my links in the code contain the write parameters, but I want to hedge against the case, when the user manually deletes the parameters in the url and just enters `/models`.